# MiniUPnP documentation

Tags: c++, nat, upnp

Anywhere I can find some documentation of [MiniUPnP](http://miniupnp.free.fr/)?

For example, some doc explains what the parameters of this function are.

```
LIBSPEC int
UPNP_AddPortMapping(const char * controlURL, const char * servicetype,
                    const char * extPort,
                    const char * inPort,
                    const char * inClient,
                    const char * desc,
                    const char * proto,
                    const char * remoteHost,
                    const char * leaseDuration);
```

Comment: Same issue here..did you found anything?

Comment: Yes, but it is in Chinese.

Comment: Can you give me a link, if you have it please?

Comment: @ManolescuSebastian It is [here](http://download.csdn.net/download/yan_mingming/4303666).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

theses are methods defined by UPnP standard.
Have a look at http://upnp.org/specs/gw/UPnP-gw-WANIPConnection-v2-Service.pdf
for UPNP_AddPortMapping.

To see more specificaly how to use with libminiupnpc, see the upnpc.c sample program.
https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/blob/master/miniupnpc/upnpc.c

Comment: Please add  more details.